# Should i verify the Google reCaptcha before submitting the form via an ajax call to my server or should i verify it along the form submission?

Tags: javascript, ajax, recaptcha, verification

Is it a good idea to verify the reCaptcha token before submission of the form using an ajax call to your own server, which will then verify the token using the private key from the google reCaptcha verify url and once verified just submit the form?

Or should i just verify the reCaptcha after submission of the form and if not verified display the form again?

Comment: the whole point of captcha is to prevent client side automation. doing it by clientside ajax only gives attackers a javascript they can manipulate and therefore bypass. having said that, doing verification both on client side and server side is probably the most secure and convenient for regular user.

Comment: Recaptcha generates a token by sending request to google from client side and then it sends that token to your server, you can append it to your form or send separately to your server.

Your server again verifies that token from the google to see if that was indeed a token provided by google.

I was just curious about this whether i should perform this server side verification separately from form or along with form.